# What happens to a sharedInstance which is not retained?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have a `sharedInstance`, created via

```
+ (TheConstantsPlaceholder *)sharedInstance
{
    static TheConstantsPlaceholder *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[TheConstantsPlaceholder alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

What happens to the object `[TheConstantsPlaceholder sharedInstance]` if it is not retained ?

Will it be deallocated immediately after its use ? If I want to use it in my program, do I have to store it in a `strong` iVar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `sharedInstance` variable is `static` it will be retain until you set the it to `nil`.

Comment: Hence the `static` keyword: it sticks.